Self-modifying LCG - thoughts?
I am a very beginner in cryptography, and I am currently interested in the problem of PRNGs. Currently I am interested in Linear Congruence Generators due to their simplicity and low memory requirements.
One thing I found was that LCGs aren't very cryptographic-ally secure, for various reasons. This is why I suggested a LCG based algorithm, to generate pseudo-random integers.

Start with the parameters of a LCG, which includes the values $A, C, M$ and the seed $S$. Then on every step, generate 4 integers: $X_0, X_1, X_2, X_3$ with the LCG. Then set $A := X_0, C = X_1, S = X_2$, yielding $X_3$ as the result of the process.

I wrote some Python code to simulate this process:
# use LCG parameters from MMIX, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use
class MY_LCG:
    def __init__(self, seed: int) -> None:
        self.m = 2 ** 64
        self.a = 6364136223846793005
        self.c = 1442695040888963407
        self.seed = seed
        
    def generate(self) -> int:
        x = []
        for _ in range(4):
            self.seed = (self.a * self.seed + self.c) % self.m
            x.append(self.seed)
        self.a, self.c, self.seed = x[0], x[1], x[2]
        return x[3]

What do you think? Would it be any better than a normal LCG when it comes to security? Would it be more practical for security purposes in devices with limited memory, or places where cryptographic security is not required?

Donald E. Knuth words in TAOCP (volume 2 IIRC) come to mind. About an anecdote on a ‘Super-random’ number generator : "The moral of this story is that random numbers should not be generated with a method chosen at random. Some theory should be used.".  In the question's context, the missing theory includes (but is not limited to): if $\gcd(a,c,m)=g$, then all later output is a multiple of $g$. This is a major flaw of the question's algorithm, at least given the choice of $m$.

Heh, that seems like a more formal quote than the "The generation of random numbers is too important to be left to chance." by Coveyou.

@fgrieu yeah I just picked some random ones. But what other theories am I missing?
